# Effective way to build a (Lazy) Map in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I know a few different a way to build a `Map` in Haskell :

1. build it from a list using `fromList`
2. build it from a sorted list using `fromAscList`
3. Use the fact that `Map` is a `Monoid` (or a `Semigroup`) and concat `singletons`.

I understand that the *amortized* complexity of  #1 is O(n*log(n)) where as #2 is  O(n).
I Guess #3 should be roughly equivalent to #1 and might be subject to fusion.

The *amortized* is important, because Haskell being lazy by default, even though the lookup from a Map is O(log(n)), it can be in practice interleaved with the construction of the Map itself which is O(n * log(n)), which can make in practice the lookup being O(n * log(n)) (especially if you are building the map each time you need it). This also might append if you use hardcoded Map

For example, am I right to think that `lookup 'b' (fromList [('a', 1), ('b', 2)])` is actually equivalent to just to d lookup in the list without using a intermediate Map ?

So is there a difference between #1 and #3 , or sorting the list and the calling `fromList` ?

### Update

Also, If I need a map to be only computed once, do I need to make sure GHC doesn't inline it, so it is shared between functions ?

### Use case

I realized that the question might be a bit blur and in fact correspond to different use cased I encountered recently.

The first one correspond to a "static join". I have an app which manages items and each item code can be split in style and variation (For example 'T-Shirt-Red' => ('T-Shirt', 'Red'). The split is based on rules (and regexp) and is quite slow. To not recompute the rules all the times, this is done once and stored in a db table. I have a few pure function which need to be able to split an item code so I pass them a function `Text -> (Text, Text)`. The function is actually a lookup partially applied on a Map. The code is similar to this

```
getSplitter :: Handler (Text -> (Text, Text))
getSplitter = do
      sku'style'vars <- runDB $ rawSQL "SELECT sku, style, var FROM style_cache " [] -- load the split table
      let sku'map = fromList [ (sku, (style,var)) 
                             | (sku, style, var) <- sku'style'vars
                             ]
      return $ flip lookup sku'map
```

This one can be easily speed up by sorting the item by `sku` and using `fromDistinctAscList` (which is actually faster than `fromAscList`). However I still have some issue about how to cache it between different request.

The second case is to do a manual join between two tables, I usually do something along

```
do
   sku'infos <- selectList [] [] -- load item info
   let skuInfo = fromList sku'infos

   orderLines <- selectList [] [] -- load orders
   -- find infos corresponding to order items
   mapM (\o -> (o, lookup (orderSku o) skuInfo) orderLines
```

There again I can sort sku'infos in SQL and use fromDistinctAscList.

A third case is when fetching miscellaneous info related to an category item in different table.

For example I want to be able to compare the sales (sales table) and the purchase (purchases table) by category.

In pure SQL I would do something along

```
SELECT style, sum(sales.amount), sum(purchase.amount)
FROM style_cache
LEFT JOIN sales USING(sku)
LEFT JOIN purchases USING(sku)
GROUP by style
```

However, this is a simplified example and in practice, the aggregation is much more complicated and have to be done in Haskell as well as the join. To do so I'm loading each table separately (grouping what I can in sql) and return a `Map Style SalesInfo`, `Map Style PurchaseInfo` etc ... and merge them. The table are quite big and I realize I end up loading everything in memory whereas I could probably by "zipping" things  manually be much more efficient but I'm not sure how.

Comment: if you want a value to be shared between different function invocations, name that value and give it a monomorphic type.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood the entire motivation behind this question, but I'll make a few comments:

1. `Map` is spine-strict -- which means the tree structure of a `Map` and the keys themselves are forced (at least far enough to do all the requisite comparisons) on every `Map` operation. So I would expect `Data.Map.lookup k (fromList xs)` to take O(n*log(n)) comparisons (n the length of `xs`) whereas I would expect `Prelude.lookup k xs` to take O(n) comparisons (actually just equality checks, but usually that's pretty much the same complexity as a comparison).
2. If `fromAscList . sort` is reliably faster than `fromList`, this is a performance bug in `Data.Map` and the library should just be changed to define `fromList = fromAscList . sort`. I would be very surprised if this were the case. People have spent a fair bit of time optimizing `containers`, so I wouldn't expect to see any fruit hanging as low as that.
3. Yes, inlining breaks sharing.

Comment: What do you mean by spine-strict ?

Comment: Under certain circumstances (lots of sorted runs), `fromAscList . sort` could be faster than `fromList`. I tried to fix that a while back but didn't quite get it. Maybe you'd like to give it a go!

Comment: @mb14 I believe I clarified what I meant by "spine-strict" immediately after introducing the term ("`Map` is spine-strict -- which means ..."). Perhaps you could clarify which part of the "..." is unclear so I can help further expand on its meaning.

Comment: I read the "which means" bit as a consequence of being spine-strict not it's definition. Now I understand. I thought naively that Lazy Map where lazy and strict Map where (fully strict). Am I wrong ?

Comment: @mb14 Lazy maps are as lazy as they can be -- values are not forced, and `seq` is not called, so any forcing that happens happens as a natural consequence of the data dependencies inherent to maintaining the data structure invariants -- but "as lazy as they can be" is still spine-strict. Strict maps, in addition to forcing the spine naturally as a consequence of the implementation needs, also force the values to WHNF during insertion and update operations.

Comment: @DanielWagner. I didn't know that. In that case a lookup is O(log(n)) (not (O(n . log(n)) as the spine has been already built and it answers my question about concatenating singletons (which then is spine-lazy and not sortable ....)

Comment: @mb14 Concatenating singletons is no lazier than `fromList`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm all confused now (which is why I think it was worth posting this question). AFAIU `fromList` is lazy, as well as the list itself, but calling `lookup` should build the full spine (is that what spine-strict means?). Concatenating singletons : the list is lazy and and the concatenation should be only be made on demand, so doing a `lookup` should stop building the spine when an element is found. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @mb14 Yes, you are wrong: as soon as the top-most constructor of a `Map` is demanded, the entire spine is evaluated. It would be very difficult, maybe impossible, to create a balanced binary (or other-ary) tree implementation which did otherwise. (It *might* be possible to make the map lazier in the spine when using `fromDistinctAscList`; I don't know off-hand whether `Map` attempts to do this or not.)